# Se detiene la camara en algunos dispositos

Tags: android, permisos

He creado una app que abre camara y galeria, el detalle es que funciona en algunos dispositivos, en otro definitivamente se detiene la app.

```
private void openCamera() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

    if(!isDirectoryCreated)
        isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

    if(isDirectoryCreated){
        Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";
        mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                + File.separator + imageName;

        File newFile = new File(mPath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
    }
}
```

el problema es con dispositivos de nueva generación

He estado viendo que en algunos dispositivos me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo eliminarlo?

Answer (score -1):

La superposicion de pantalla es un permiso que sale a pantalla cuando una aplicacion desea sobreponerse por encima de otras aplicaciones. Personalmente nunca pude quitar este error de manera programatica y en muchos foros encontre que esto depende del sistema operativo, por lo cual no tienes mucho control sobre esto. Para que funciono te recomiendo que entres en aplicaciones y le des ese permiso a tu app de manera manual y si eso no funciona debes buscar la app que esta intentado sobre ponerse cuando accedes a la camara. Muchas veces quien genera este comportamiento son las burbujas de chat de facebook. En caso de que las tengas desactivadas e intenta de nuevo. De resto, no tengo otra solucion con respecto a este problema.